# which are default font comes with all android 2.1 and above

Tags: android, fonts

I want list of fonts used by the android framework.

Comment: What about later android release ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you see in the [class Typeface,](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) there's `SANS_SERIF`, `SERIF` and `MONOSPACE`.

Comment: only 3 ... there is something called as [DEFAULT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#DEFAULT") what that refer to ?

Answer (score 11):

The three provided fonts in android (through 2.3 at least) are:

- [Droid Serif](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Serif) (`Typeface.SERIF`)
- [Droid Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans) (`Typeface.SANS_SERIF`)
- [Droid Sans Mono](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Droid+Sans+Mono) (`Typeface.MONOSPACE`)

If you don't specify a typeface, the default is usually `Typeface.SANS_SERIF`